# Extrating jUnit test methods in interface

Tags: java, junit4

Is it possible to declare methods in an interface with the annotation @Test and to use them in a concrete class.
My problem is, that the class implementing the interface has the annotation @Override and not @Test. Is there a solution or do I have to use a parent class?

Comment: You can use both `@Override` and `@Test` in your implementing class - is that an issue?

Comment: But if I use `@Test` in the interface and if I implement the interface in a concrete class, Eclipse uses `@Override` and jUnit does not recognize the `@Test` annotation automatically. I would like to get the `@Test` annotation without adding it manually in the concrete class.

Comment: Why do you use interfaces for test classes? This is highly unusual.

Comment: Test classes are usually very specific to Implementation , i couldnt sense a reason why we need generic interface out of TEST classes, could you please mention specific requirements if any

Comment: I'm testing webpages with a very similiar structure and I have for each page a test class. So I would like to structure the methods in one interface for all the different pages and there classes. But meanwhile I'm using a abstract parent class, but I'm not really satisfied. To my mind, a interface would give a better style and structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `abstract class` instead of `interface`.
You can mark methods in `absctract class` with annotation `@Test`
**1)**

```
public interface ITest {
   @Test
   public void simpleTest();
} 

public class SimpleTest implements ITest
{
   @Override
   public void simpleTest()
   {
      Assert.assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

we get

```
Tests in error: 
  initializationError(com.company.tester.SimpleTest)
```

**2)**

```
public interface ITest {

   public void simpleTest();
}  

public class SimpleTest implements ITest
{

   @Test
   @Override
   public void simpleTest()
   {
      Assert.assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

all works well, test is passed!

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

**3)** Abstract class

```
public abstract class ATest {

   @Test
   public abstract void simpleTest();
} 

public class SimpleTest extends ATest
{
   @Override
   public void simpleTest()
   {
      Assert.assertTrue(true);
   }
}  

public class SecondTest extends ATest
{
   @Override
   public void simpleTest()
   {
      Assert.assertFalse(false);
   }
}
```

tests are passed well!

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```